# How do I change user agent to mobile device? And is it safe?

Tags: configuration, mobile

On desktop version of Tor, I want to change the user agent in the configuration, just to be able to visit mobile sites. 
If it's safe, could you tell me how to choose One? (It seems I can choose general.useragent.override, but when I choose it and hit enter, nothing happens.)

Edit:
Sorry, safe against ... I don't even know, but when I go to about:config, it gives me a warning "you could void warranty = conpromise security?"

Comment: Safe against what?

Comment: Potentially you will compromise your anonymity/indistinguishability.

Comment: about:config warns you because if you change the wrong settings, you could break the browser entirely. If you know what you're changing, you should be fine in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe as it will makes you stand out from other Tor browsers as they have standardized user agent. And also I am sure many websites has mobile versions of their pages. Maybe web searching or visiting their site maps will help you find these pages for mobile?