# How to change user agent string on Tor to see mobile sites?

Tags: anonymity

I asked this question but got logged out and can't get back in but need to ask additional Q...
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131165/how-can-i-see-mobile-version-websites-on-pc-mac-while-using-a-privacy-secure-bro

I tried the user agent string as explained in the answer, but it didn't work, so I'd like to know what I am doing wrong? I change the useragent to exactly what's in the answer and hit "enter" and go to youtube, right? My youtube still displays as desktop. I'm on a Mac. Thanks.

Comment: You can ask a Mod to merge your two accounts.

Comment: Are you using Tor Browser? Privoxy?

Comment: I think this question may be more suited for [tor.se] website.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12221/how-do-i-change-user-agent-to-mobile-device-and-is-it-safe

Answer (score 2):

Type `about:config` in the address bar. Hit enter.
Search for `privacy.resistFingerprinting` and disable it.
Now you can set the useragent by creating a new String entry `general.useragent.override`

Read more: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/26146

Answer (score 1):

Two potential solutions (I'm sure there are others).

1.) If you want to maximize your privacy you could simply use tor "as-is" and go to a website which will show you a mobile version of a site. For example:
http://ready.mobi/

2.) You could also increase your privacy risk and change the Tor user agent setting itself:

```
   Open the Tor Browser and go to the url about:config
   Say Yes you'll be careful
   Search for useragent
   Change general.useragent.override to the value of your choice
```

Note: If you are the only Tor browser with a specific user agent you'll be pretty easy to identify but it all depends on what you are doing.

Additional Note: You may want to clear your cookies. If the first time you've visited a site it set a cookie regarding your screen size that may be part of what is affecting your user experience.

I just successfully did this on OSX 10.10.5 using Tor Browser 45.2.0 changing the Tor user agent string from

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
```

to

```
Apple-iPhone7C2/1202.466
```

and was able to view YouTube as a mobile browser.

User Agent String Reference:
http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings

Website to see your User Agent string remotely once you change it.
http://www.whatsmyua.com/