# User Agent Change in Tor for Android

Tags: configuration, android

general.useragent.override is absent in Tor for Android.  Does this mean that user agent changes are not possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change user agent string on Tor to see mobile sites?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12248/how-to-change-user-agent-string-on-tor-to-see-mobile-sites)